# Custom field get meta Value

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce

I Want to get a meta value `445` but it shows this meta value

Meta Key: `festiUserRolePrices`

Meta Value: `{"cash_elit_car":"445","salePrice":{"cash_elit_car":"","elite_car":""},"schedule":{"cash_elit_car":{"date_from":"","date_to":""},"elite_car":{"date_from":"","date_to":""}},"elite_car":"422"}`

this is my code to fetch that data.

```
//load the custom price for our product
    $custom_price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'cash_elit_car', true );
```

i think that meta value is `json_decode` here but im not familiar on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_decode and from there pick the data you need.

For testing

```
function test() {
    $value = '{"cash_elit_car":"445","salePrice":{"cash_elit_car":"","elite_car":""},"schedule":{"cash_elit_car":{"date_from":"","date_to":""},"elite_car":{"date_from":"","date_to":""}},"elite_car":"422"}';
    $value = json_decode($value);
    error_log(print_r($value,true));
}
```

That will return the following:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [cash_elit_car] => 445
    [salePrice] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cash_elit_car] => 
            [elite_car] => 
        )

    [schedule] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cash_elit_car] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [date_from] => 
                    [date_to] => 
                )

            [elite_car] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [date_from] => 
                    [date_to] => 
                )

        )

    [elite_car] => 422
)
```

From there you can convert it to array if you want and get your value:

```
 $value = get_object_vars($value);
 $cash_elit_car = $value['cash_elit_car'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. @Martin Mirchev. but `$custom_price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'cash_elit_car', true );` what seems to be can replace here to get the meta of all `'cash_elit_car` products?

Comment: use the key you mention ? festiUserRolePrices